# DHKE choice of private keys

Tags: diffie-hellman

In some literature it is written that the private key should be chosen random from

{2,3, ..., p-1}

and in some it says

{2,3, ..., p-2}

I guess p-1 is a weak private key, but why is that so?
The calculation would be:

A = k <sub>pub, A</sub> = α<sup>p-1</sup> mod p

Comment: I wonder why $1$ is missing in your examples, it looks like a perfectly fine private key to me. I'd choose the private key $x$ to fulfill $0<x<q$ where $q$ is the order of the generator (typically $(p-1)/2$).

Comment: if the private key is 1, the private key would be the same as the public key

Comment: Obviously the shared secret would be the same as the public key if the private key is 1. But I don't see how that's a problem. A good stream cipher occasionally outputs zero bytes as well, in which case the ciphertext byte will equal the plaintext byte.

Comment: DHKE enables two parties to derive a common secret key by communicating over an insecure channel, if one of the public keys equals 1 the secret key is 1 too. Either way it's not "secret", because Oscar knows it aswell.

Comment: You can apply the same logic to any particular private key. The attacker guessing correctly that your private key is 1 is just as unlikely as the attacker correctly guessing it's another value. 1 isn't special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p-1$ is certainly a weak private key, in that it forces the shared secret to be a constant value as:

$a^{p-1} \bmod p = 1$

(This is known as Fermat's Little Theorem; no relation to Fermat's Last Theorem)

Hence, if either side uses $p-1$ as there private key, then both sides would arrive at the value of 1, and that's not great for security.

Comment: thanks, totally forgot fermat's little theorem there, guess that solved it

Comment: If you forbid $p-1$, shouldn't you also forbid $(p-1)/2$?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: probably.  Now, when I do DH, I pick a secret randomly from a range such as $[1, 2^{128}]$; that keeps the DLOG problem just as hard, makes the computation cheaper (and incidentally avoids hard cases such as $(p-1)/2$

Comment: Doesn't a 128 bit exponent result in a 64 bit security level? A 256 bit exponent might be wiser.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: oops, you're right -- I typo'ed that - I meant to say $[1,2^{256}]$.